# How to calculate the expected zeros in a Poisson distribution?

Tags: distributions, generalized-linear-model, poisson-distribution, zero-inflation

I am modelling the nights spent at hotels (count data) fitting a few predictors in the model.

I'd like to know how to calculate the expected number of zeros in this distribution, as I suspect that I should move to a zero-inflated Poisson distribution.

Comment: If you're asking how to calculate the expected number of zeroes under a fitted Poisson distribution, $Pr[X=0] = \lambda^0e^{-\lambda}/0! = e^{-\lambda}$. So expected number of zeroes is $Ne^{-\lambda}$ where $N$ is the number of observations in your data set.

Comment: @M.Berk -- that would work if the GLM had the same Poisson distribution for every observation.

Comment: @Glen_b Yes, my mistake. I was focusing on the title and overlooked the details of the question.

Answer (score 4):

With the model you can readily compute the conditional probability of a zero; to compute the overall expected number of zeros (conditional on the whole set of observed x's) is less direct, but still simple.

That is, at a given combination of the the $x$'s you can compute $(\hat\lambda_i|\mathbf{x}_i)$  (where $\mathbf{x}_i$ represents the collection of independent variables for the ith observation).

and hence get an estimate of $P(Y_i=0|\mathbf{x}_i)$: $e^{-\hat\lambda}$

That is, compute the fitted mean for each point, and then calculate as above - exponentiate the negative of that mean.

The expected number of zeroes overall will be sum of those probabilities of zero calculated from those fitted means across all the data points.